# Excel doesn't want to open XLSX files downloaded through ASP output

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel, download

I use ASP MVC3 framework, created an Excel file and outputted it using FileResult action with content type "**application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet**".

When attempting to open it Excel just says "**file is corrupt and cannot be opened**."

When I open the source generated Excel file that was used to send the output it works without any problems. I also run file comparison on the bytes for both copies and the files are identical. I tried to email the corrupt file to myself and the attachment opens fine.

This leads me to believe it's a problem with headers or some sort of Excel/Windows security config.

If it is the latter, then I need a solution that won't make clients change their security settings.

**EDIT - Found the setting:**

I've found what setting causes this - "**Enable protected view from files originated from the internet**" in Excel's **Trust Center / Protected View** settings.

So I guess the question is - **Is there a way for the file to appear trusted?**

**Here are the response headers:**

- Cache-Control:private
- Content-Disposition:attachment;
- filename="Report - Monday, March 19, 2012.xlsx" Content-Length:20569
- Content-Type:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

**The action method that makes the output:**

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual FileResult Export()
    {   
        try
        {
            ...
            string newFilePath = createNewFile(...);
            string downloadedFileName = "Report - " + DateTime.Now.ToString("D") + ".xlsx";
            return File(newFilePath, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", downloadedFileName);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

**How I create the Excel file:**

I have a template XLSX file witch column names and some pivot charts in other sheets. From C# I create a copy of this template and then call SQL Server which outputs data into 1st sheet using OLEDB connector:

```
set @SQL='insert into OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'', ''Excel 12.0;Database=' +     @PreparedXLSXFilePath + ';'', ''SELECT * FROM [Data$]'')  ...
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: How are you creating the Excel file? Depending on what you're using, this may be of help: http://www.jwgoerlich.us/blogengine/post/2009/08/11/Excel-Extension-Hardening-and-Web-Applications.aspx

Comment: Found the problematic setting - updated in question. I need to find a way to make the file trusted without any work on client's side.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a digital signature in your Excel file. How to do this from code is another question.

More info here:

http://www.delphifaq.com/faq/windows_user/f2751.shtml

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this later today.

Comment: Good luck:) The certificate should be a trusted one or the client won't accept it (or needs to be installed on client's personal store)..

Comment: Ok, I looked into the digital signatures but that has 1 major problem - you can't modify the file without invaliding the signature. This doesn't even let the pivot tables refresh plus I expect clients to work with the supplied data.

Comment: But is the file trusted when the client opens the Excel file for the first time? Does it matter the file is invalidated after the client changes the file?

Comment: I didn't test the actual download before cause the issue ruled out the use of digital signature. Now I did a quick test and got the corrupted error again but maybe I did something wrong cause the signature is marked as invalid after I open the file - I'm guessing that's because of the pivot tables trying to modify data. At any rate, I cannot present a solution to the clients where they get error messages on opening the doc. Anyway, thank you for bringing up this idea.

Answer (score 0):

The file being written is basically just an HTML version of the data table (change the extension to .txt and open it and see).  This is why it's showing up as an error.  If you save the file as a .xls instead of .xlsx, Excel should still open it.

(I understand that this issue is over ten years old, but I just came across it myself, so this is for anyone who comes after.)